# Why are the timestamps not stored in UTC time?

Tags: java, postgresql, timezone, jodatime, jooq

I am having a `store_time_period` that is supposed to hold two `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE`. I am using joda `org.joda.time.DateTime` instead of `java.sql.Timestamp` and I am initializing my variables like e.g. this:

```
DateTime day_from = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

However, in phpPgAdmin what I see is this string:

> 2016-01-06 20:14:09.339+01

instead of

> 2016-01-06 19:14:09.339+00

for UTC time. Why is that so?

This is how I convert `DateTime` and `TimeStamp`:

```
public class JodaDateTimeConverter implements Converter<Timestamp, DateTime> {
    @Override
    public DateTime from(Timestamp timestamp) {
        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(timestamp.getTime());
        return dateTime;
    }

    @Override
    public Timestamp to(DateTime dateTime) {
        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(dateTime.getMillis());
        return timestamp;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Timestamp> fromType() {
        return Timestamp.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<DateTime> toType() {
        return DateTime.class;
    }
}
```

And here is the PostgreSQL code for `store_time_period`:

```
CREATE TABLE store_time_period (

    -- PRIMARY KEY

    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,

    -- ATTRIBUTES

    day_from TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, 
    day_to TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: I am not a specialist of PostgreSQL nor of phpPgAdmin. But what I am thinking of is that either phpPgAdmin is set up to display local time and/or PostgreSQL is set up to store local time. You can check the PostgreSQL by using command line connection if it exists or using java code again.

Comment: It probably *is* being stored in UTC.  You're just seeing it converted to a time zone when you view it.

Comment: @MattJohnson But why doesn't it convert it back to the timezone I stored it in? I can't imagine that phpPgAdmin just converts every timestamp to my local time. Why would it do that? But I will try it out.

Comment: It doesn't *store* the time zone.  It uses the session time zone at time of retrieval.  (If you're used to `datetimeoffset` in SQL Server, which *does* store the offset - this is not the same behavior.)

Comment: Actually - nevermind the session timezone.  That's *sometimes* the case, but in your case there's a simpler answer.  I'll write an answer shortly...

Answer (score 1):

This behavior conforms to the definition of the `timestamp with time zone` data type, from:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html

> For timestamp with time zone, **the internally stored value is always in
>   UTC (Universal Coordinated Time**, traditionally known as Greenwich Mean
>   Time, GMT). An input value that has an explicit time zone specified is
>   converted to UTC using the appropriate offset for that time zone. If
>   no time zone is stated in the input string, then it is assumed to be
>   in the time zone indicated by the system's TimeZone parameter, and is
>   converted to UTC using the offset for the timezone zone.
>
> When a timestamp with time zone value is output, **it is always
>   converted from UTC to the current timezone zone, and displayed as
>   local time in that zone**. To see the time in another time zone, either
>   change timezone or use the AT TIME ZONE construct (see Section 9.9.3).

with the parts that exactly answer your questions in bold face.

Comment: Hm, but I create a `DateTime` in the UTC timezone: `DateTime day_from = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);`.

Comment: @Stefan: presumably you're assuming that it should store this timezone along with the datetime and then return it back unmodified when you read back the column. It's a frequent misunderstanding due to the name of the type, but that's now how it works. The input timezone is only used to compute the UTC value, and then it's lost.

Comment: Okay, that is freaked up. So I want a `TIMESTAMP` **with** timezone but what I get is a UTC timestamp that gets converted to the current timezone that the machine is running on/in as it says in "*it is always converted from UTC to the current timezone zone, and displayed as local time in that zone*"? Because that's absolutely not what I want. I want to get UTC out if I put UTC in ^^

Comment: @Stefan: consider either `timestamp without time zone` (if you're only ever interested in UTC), or if you wish to keep the original time zone or offset to GMT, you want to add a separate column to store it.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, when you construct a `DateTime`, you're using the constructor that accepts the `long` timestamp.  The timestamp itself is UTC-based, despite using `timestamp with time zone` in postgres, because postgres does not *store* the time zone.

That particular constructor says [in the javadocs](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime-long-):

> Constructs an instance set to the milliseconds from `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z` using `ISOChronology` ***in the default time zone***.

The key being that the default time zone (either your system's local time zone, or the one you have explicitly set with [`DateTimeZone.setDefault`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#setDefault-org.joda.time.DateTimeZone-)) is used when you do not specify a time zone.

If you can determine the time zone with some other means (perhaps stored elsewhere in your application or database), then you can use [the constructor of `DateTime` that accepts a `DateTimeZone` as a second parameter](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime-long-org.joda.time.DateTimeZone-).

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem on the JDBC *and* database level. You're using a `java.sql.Timestamp` on your `Converter<T, U>` as the `<T>` type. jOOQ will bind this timestamp to JDBC, which specifies that `Timestamp` is your *local time*.

Note that jOOQ's code generator doesn't fully support `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` yet. This is a pending feature request:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4429

If you want to bind joda time's `DateTime`, you'll have to use an [`org.jooq.Binding`](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-bindings/) to implement the binding on the JDBC level yourself. That way, you're in full control of what is sent to the server and retrieved from it.